# When does recvfrom() return 0 with a UDP socket?

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I check the return value of recvfrom() in this way:
`while ((n = recvfrom(sockfd, buf, BUF_SIZE, 0, NULL, NULL)) > 0)`
I try to close the socket of the sender but recvfrom() still blocks. The manual says that recvfrom() returns 0 when the peer has performed an orderly shutdown. It's useless to shutdown a UDP socket, right?
Any answer will be appreciated. Thx.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The return value of `recvfrom` is the amount of user data in the datagram received. A return value of `0` is acceptable for UDP: It does not mean that the peer has closed the connection, because writing a datagram of length 0 is acceptable.